# Why can I access kubernetes pod from any worker and master public IP?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is it normal that I can access a pod through any worker node IP and also through master node IP?

`kubectl get pods -o wide` shows that the pod is on one specific worker node but I can access it from any master or woker public IP. I have 1 replica of that pod.

Can someone help explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible if you are using NodePort type service. It's because by design the NodePort is opened on all nodes in the cluster including master nodes.

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types)

**NodePort**: Exposes the Service on *each Node's IP* at a static port (the NodePort). A ClusterIP Service, to which the NodePort Service routes, is automatically created. You'll be able to contact the NodePort Service, from outside the cluster, by requesting `<NodeIP>:<NodePort>`

If you are looking for a way to avoid this use [ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) with `ClusterIP` type service.